# Headless Chrome find input field on page

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I initialized `driver` as shown below:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

I get following message, when I execute test.

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763
>   (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 44655 Only local
>   connections are allowed.
>
> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds
>   waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath:

Given xpath belongs to an input field, which opens a file selector when clicked. It is working perfectly in a normal `Firefox`.
I use `WebDriverWait` to wait until necessary elements appear.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(mainPage.InputFileField));
```

Answer (score 2):

When the --headless argument is declared, the driver is thrown to the minimized window 50%, regardless of the " --start-maximized " argument or the 
" driver.manage()window().maximize(); " command.

If your page has a different DOM in 50% responsive mode, then it does not find the DOM elements of the nonresponsive mode.

If that is the case :

- Either you adapt your query selector to take into account the repsonsive mode
- Or you add after the instantiation of your driver:

  this.webDriver.manage (). window (). setSize (new Dimension (1440, 900));

Sorry for my bad English, but I hope this will help more than one ;)

Comment: Sorry, but I use `driver.manage().window().maximize();` already in code and it doesn't help.

Comment: Hello, driver.manage().window().maximize(); doesn't work with headless mode. Try : driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1440, 900));

Comment: I tried this too, but has same effect, but found problem, it is caused by untrusted SSL cert in HTTPS. How could I ignore these errors in headless mode?

Comment: To accept all SSL certificate in chrome and not receive SSL certificate errors: `caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);` after your `DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();`

Comment: I initialize variable as follows, but it is not working: `driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs).addArguments("--start-maximized").addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors").setHeadless(true));`

Comment: did you use this.webDriver.manage (). window (). setSize (new Dimension (1440, 900)); after your instantiation of webdriver? instead of adding the --start-maximized argument that is not supported in headless mode
Because currently your window is defaulted at 50%, and so is in repsonsive mode